# Installed SQL Developer but no option to launch?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I downloaded and installed SQL Developer from the [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/downloads/101202winsoft-087370.html).

There didn't seem to be any problems with the installation but after it was completed, I could not find a .exe file to launch the program. Below is a screenshot of the directory that the developer suite was installed in.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Installation Directory Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRYPz.png)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't SQL Developer directory; it belongs to Developer Suite (Forms & Reports, that is). You should have paid more attention to what you do and *remember* how you named directory you extracted SQL Developer to.